# BIND9 reverse DNS, /16 zone

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns

I'm trying to set up a reverse zone for the entire 10.200.x.x/16 subnet. I've configured everything according to named.conf and several different blog posts, but no luck.

Note that the A-records resolve correctly, the problem is reverse lookups.

Can anyone spot any configuration errors?

named.conf:

```
zone "200.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/master/10.200.reverse";
};
```

10.200.reverse:

```
$TTL 3600
@                       IN SOA  dhcpns01.guest.domain.com. admin.domain.com. (
                                2011022106 ; serial
                                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                38400      ; minimum (10 hours 40 minutes)
                                )
; name servers
                        NS      dhcpns01.guest.domain.com.
; hosts
0.10                    PTR     dhcpns01.guest.domain.com.
```

dig -t ptr 10.200.0.10 @127.0.0.1

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 15066
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;10.200.0.10.                   IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       10800   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2011022001 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 21 12:19:31 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

Disclaimer: This is edited down to be more viewable. I'm not using a single nameserver :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your entry is for 10.200.10.0, not 10.200.0.10.

Try:

```
 10.0                    PTR     dhcpns01.guest.domain.com.
```

EDIT: You might want to try the dig like this:

```
dig -t ptr 10.0.200.10.in-addr.arpa. @127.0.0.1
```

OR

```
dig -x 10.200.0.10 @127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Try the amended dig (with the 10.0 PTR)

Answer (score 1):

Correct PTR to 10.200.0.10:

```
10.0                    PTR     dhcpns01.guest.domain.com.
```

Comment: See comment on Cakemox's answer